# for() statement in PHP if not equal to FALSE

Tags: php, for-loop, codeigniter-2

I'am working in CodeIgniter, and want to create a dynamic breadcrumbs by using `$this->uri->segment($i)` function.

How should I write correctly `for()` statement if I want to test the *2nd expression* that is not equal to FALSE ? It gives me an infinite loop and I don't know why.

here is my code:

```
for($i = 1; $i !== FALSE; $i++){
    var_dump($this->uri->segment($i));
}
```

For exemple, first 3 reccursion should output a different strings, starting from 4th reccursion, it gives me `false` but it's not working here, know someone why ?

Comment: Is this a infinite loop? I think you can use while loop and break the loop when reaching the last item

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$i` variable is an integer, and will never be equal to `FALSE`.

Maybe you are looking for comparing `$this->uri->segment($i)`?

```
for($i = 1; $this->uri->segment($i) !== FALSE; $i++){
    var_dump($this->uri->segment($i));
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I didn't realized it should be written in that way.